# Unity player stops falling when colliding with wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I move my player character in the direction of a wall as it is falling the y velocity changes to some extremely small number, that is effectively zero. I presume this is because the player clips into the wall for a frame and loses all of its downward momentum.

I've considered a slightly larger collision that preemptively stops the player from moving in the direction of a wall that they are pressed against, but that solution seems a bit clunky. I'm wondering if anyone has a better solution to this issue or if something else is wrong with my program.

The movement code is as follows:

```
void Update()
    {
        float xMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float zMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(xMove * (movSpeed * speedMult), rb.velocity.y, zMove * (movSpeed * speedMult)) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the player and the wall have friction, which can cause the player to stick to the wall.Attach a Physic Material to them.

Asset -> double click -> create Physic Material -> set friction=0 ->drag it onto the player

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Since it seems like there's no simple solutions, I just ended up implementing my previously proposed solution where I created some extra hitboxes that preemptively shut down specific directional movement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).